# Online account settings freeze when clicked

Tags: gnome, software-center, online-accounts

I want to add my Google account, but the settings page instantly freezes when I click on Google. The same happens for the Microsoft, Flickr, foursquare and Microsoft exchange options. So everything that uses SSO? The other options give a little system pop-up where I can enter my credentials and connect without issue.

On my first clean install, I could use my Google account without any issues. This sadly lasted only for 2 days.

I've tried:

- Disabling ipv6
- Rebooting my router
- Reinstalling gnome
- Use a VPN
- Run gnome-control-center from the terminal to collect some logs, which resulted in this:

```
(gnome-control-center:10442): dconf-WARNING **: 14:13:23.381: Unable to open /usr/local/share/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
bwrap: Can't find source path /usr/local/share: Permission denied
```

This output is generated when I open gnome settings, after that nothing, not even when it eventually crashes. I collect the output with command `gnome-control-center > ~/errorerror.txt 2>&1`

- Suggestions?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on Parrot OS 5.0 (Electro Ara) as well.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about the cause, but the WEBKIT_FORCE_SANDBOX answer didn't fix it for me, instead I had to do the following

1. Open a Terminal
2. Enter `export WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1` press enter
3. Enter `gnome-control-center` and proceed with adding the account without a crash.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to set that value when the computer starts?

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal, run:

```
export WEBKIT_FORCE_SANDBOX=0
gnome-control-center
```

That should get the settings dialogs to work. It appears that the GNOME Control Center ("Settings") -> Online Accounts dialogs use WebKit to prompt for additional details. WebKit is affected by a bug in at a particular package release. A bug report from Mageia has additional details: https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30041. I was able to reproduce and test the work-around on Parrot OS 5.0.

Missing from this Answer are confirmation that this work-around succeeds with Ubuntu and a link to an authoritative bug report to track the fix upstream. This should be a temporary work-around until the patched package or packages roll forward.

Comment: This fixed it for me.