# GNOME Control Center freezes when trying to add a Gmail account

Tags: online-accounts, gnome-control-center, webkit, geary, oauth

I want to add a Google account on my gnome-control-center online-account. The popup OAuth window for connecting GNOME to Google loads the first page (email), but when I validate, the window freezes and I can't enter my password and validate the connection.

OAuth window freezes:

[image: OAuth window freezes]

I get this first window so it's not a graphics driver problem as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424005/pop-up-window-goes-blank-when-adding-google-account-in-gnome-control-center?rq=1).

It was working fine until I tried to add another google account (reason for my initial message below), but this may well be completely unrelated, whatever Occam has to say about this.

The problem I have is very similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382602/online-account-settings-freeze-when-clicked). I tried both solutions with ENV vars, the first deprecated one `WEBKIT_FORCE_SANDBOX=0`, and the new `WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1`, with no success.

Here are [the log of gnome-control-center -v](https://pastebin.com/yirf4qZL) when trying to add a Gmail online-account. The many lines with `reading data from TLS connection has failed: WOULD_BLOCK` lead me to several threads related to my problem:

- [this thread on archlinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254251) which is exactly the same as mine,but does not provide any answer,
- [this thread on gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-online-accounts/-/issues/109) which is a bit different and does not provide solutions either.

I tried updating, removing and reinstalling gnome-control-center, online-account and Geary.

I also had a low memory problem on my system disk, that I solved before trying those updates.

below is my original message*

I have several Google accounts, for the different organizations I work for.

I want to use Geary for those emails. And Geary uses gnome online accounts, to my knowledge.

It seems that you can't add several Gmail accounts. When I try, I can enter my Gmail address in the first Oauth2 window, but when I press Enter nothing happens.

I also tried to had an IMAP and SMTP account, and copy the working settings from Thunderbird, but you can't use OAuth with this option (yet).

Firefox's second Gmail account settings:

[image: Firefox's second Gmail account settings]

Maybe there's a way by manually copying some files.

Comment: I found this thread but so far it doesn'e work : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382602/online-account-settings-freeze-when-clicked

Comment: The problem I'm facing is exactly the same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382602/online-account-settings-freeze-when-clicked

Comment: Thanks for the edit karel

Comment: It still doesn't work, any idea ?